# In onActivityResult getIntent().getSerializableExtra is null

Tags: android, android-intent

In onActivityResult(), getIntent().getSerializableExtra() is null. But when I check the putSerializable() value, it is not null, and the tag is the same. But in iputTextActivity, I receive the valid value. Why?

class daygramActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode!= Activity.RESULT_OK)  
        return;

    if(requestCode == 1){   
        if(data==null){
            return;
        }

        Message msg = (Message) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(iputTextActivity.IPUT_TEXT_RETURN_CONTENT); 
        if(msg == null)  //I receive null
            return;

        updateData(1); 
    }
}
```

class iputTextActivity:

```
final Message msg = (Message) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(daygramActivity.SER_KEY);  //I receive valid                   //value

mDoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        EditText edT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String input = edT.getText().toString();

        Intent data=new Intent(); 

        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        msg.setContent(input);
        mBundle.putSerializable(IPUT_TEXT_RETURN_CONTENT,msg);
        data.putExtras(mBundle);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `Intent` passed to `onActivityResult()` instead of calling `getIntent()`. When you call `getIntent()` in an `Activity` it returns the `Intent` used to start that `Activity`. In this case by calling `getIntent()` it will return a reference to the `Intent` that was used to start your daygramActivity `Activity`. It will not return the `Intent` you used when you called `setResult()`. Instead, the `Intent` used when you call `setResult()` is made available to you as the `Intent` parameter in `onActivityResult()`.

So in `onActivityResult()` change this:

```
Message msg = (Message) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(iputTextActivity.IPUT_TEXT_RETURN_CONTENT);
```

to this:

```
Message msg = (Message) data.getSerializableExtra(iputTextActivity.IPUT_TEXT_RETURN_CONTENT);
```